# 404 not found error when apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, repository

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 on a Digital Ocean image. I try to run this command:

> sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng

but I get these specific error messages in output;

```
Err:3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.37 80]
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]

E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So I tried given solutions in these sources:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800051/repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-error
>
> [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)
>
> https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-404-not-found-repository-errors

Besides, I tried `apt update` and got the same errors above.

Comment: "kinetic" (22.10) was just released so it makes no sense to have an "old-releases" repository, it doesn't exist. You need to correct that either by editing or removing. The PPA exists but hasn't been updated since 2021 therefore it has nothing for your release. Remove it.

Comment: you mean from ```source.list``` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party software sources so all security checks are on you to perform before adding..  A quick glance & I can see the PPA you added hasn't had any attention since 2020 (20.04) and provides no support for later release; did you check?  It has nothing helpful for 22.10 and the lack of maintenance should have *felt* a security risk to you (https://launchpad.net/~brightbox/+archive/ubuntu/ruby-ng)